# authenticating to a ProtoRPC service

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication

How does one authenticate to a ProtoRPC service?

It seems like a web services infrastructure, but designed for non-browser clients, so how do we authenticate the service's end user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, ProtoRPC can be used by browser clients, usually through AJAX requests.

Now for authentication on App Engine, there are a few possibilities:

1. You can use the built in user authentication app engine provides
2. You can build an authentication mechanism of your own

For the first one there is the regular Google accounts API, openID and OAuth.

If you have users with google accounts, and you don't need to perform actions on user's behalf (which is what OAuth is for), then you can use the regular google authentication.

This requires the client to have a google cookie. If the user is on browser, he can login to google and then he can access your app. If the user is on a mobile client, then for android there is the `AccountManager` API which gets you a Google token which the client uses to get an App Engine cookie, as explained here http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app

I'm not sure if iOS has something similar to `AccountManager`. If the OS doesn't have the user's credentials then AFAIK you might have to go through some sort of browser authentication.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, the question was more about the client. I.e. how do you authenticate a user without using google's login page? Is there a way to use basic authentication? What kind of security is provided? (plain text is no longer an option this days)

Comment: Do you want authentication with your own username and password or through google account or any other provider?

Comment: I want users to authenticate using their own Google accounts. The client is not a web browser, so redirecting them to the Google login page using users.create_login_url() is not an option.

Comment: I'm assuming the client is a mobile app? In android you can get a Google token through the android AccountManager API, then use this token to get an app engine cookie, no browser required.

Comment: I'm not targeting any one specific platform, so Android only solution would not do the job.